# Computational Maths

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

[image]

I'm trying to revise for a test and these 2 questions I just don't really understand what I'm meant to do, any pointers would be good.

Any help I'd be very grateful for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first, you should start by carrying out the calculations with the indicated number of significant figures.

On the second, you have 8 bits minus 3 bits = 5 bits for the number, and without a hidden bit you have numbers of the form x.xxxx in binary. How many significant digits is this in decimal? Set this number to the largest possible, and set the exponent to the largest possible. What do you get? For the smallest positive number you want a small exponent and a small but nonzero number.

Once you know the largest number you can represent, finding how big to make it to get overflow should be easy.

Comment: I'm still unsure on number two, is the exponent as large as possible at 5? and as small as possible at negative 5?

Comment: making the largest number 10000 and smallest 0.0001? also what does it mean by overflow?

Comment: The exponent is 1 bit long. What is the largest number you can store in 1 bit?

Comment: largest would be 11111?